# Unable to set env vairables using runtime.exec

Tags: java, unix

I have to execute a unix command from my Java program and prior to executing the command, need to set some env variables.

But I am unable to set the env variables because of which the unix command is not a success.

Here is my code snippet:

```
String[] cmd=new String[] {
                "/u01/IDMTOP/products/dir/oid/bin/ldapmodify",
                "-h ",
                oid_host,
                "-p ",
                oid_port,
                "-D ",
                oid_user,
                "-w ",
                oid_password,
                "-c ",
                "-v ",
                "-f ",
                filename};

        String[] envp = new String[] {
                "OARCLE_HOME=" + "/u01/IDMTOP/products/dir/oid",
                "INSTANCE_HOME=" + "/u01/IDMTOP/config/instances/oid1" };
        System.out.println(cmd);
        try {
            Process p;
            p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, envp);
```

Comment: Please show us the stack trace or error messages

Comment: My typo mistake :( Should use ORACLE_HOME

Comment: does it work when you use `ORACLE_HOME` as suggested by Nizil?

Comment: Yes, it works prefectly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by setting the proper variable, `ORACLE_HOME` and not `OARCLE_HOME` :)

Comment: I think this is not an answer, just a comment (albeit a helpful one). Please edit it to answer the question, rather than make a comment which, although helpful, will not solve the main problem

Comment: @OurManInBananas Actually, OP said it was a simple typo error so... I will delete my answer if if doesn't solve his issue ;)

Comment: if it was just a type, then the question will be flagged for closure as `Off Topic: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error`...in the meantime, please change your answer to a comment - this will avoid anyone having to flag it *Low Quality* or *Not an answer*

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you *are* setting the environment variables.  It's just that the shell you create when you do so then exits, and they disappear again.

This is a common mistake. Environment variables are set in the current shell process; if they are set and `export`ed, they're then shared to any *child* processes.

You need to set these in the environment external to your Java process